# Get element scope from attribute directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to extend functionality of *any* directive by simply attaching an attribute directive, but I'm having trouble getting the scope of the element on which the attribute is defined.

For example, I have this template:

```
<div class="flex-item-grow flex-item flex-column report-area">
    <sv-report sv-reloadable id="reportId"></sv-report>
</div>
```

Here, `sv-reloadable` has some implicit understanding of `sv-report`, but `sv-report` has *no idea* about `sv-reloadable`.

I've defined `sv-reloadable` as:

```
angular
    .module( 'sv-reloadable', [
        'sv.services',
    ])
    .directive('svReloadable', function(reportServices, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
                $scope.$on('parameter-changed', function(evt, payload) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    $scope.viewModel = getNewViewModel(payload);/* hit the server to retrieve new data */
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Now, `$scope` in `sv-reloadable` is the *parent* scope of `sv-report`. I'm wanting `sv-reloadable` to be able to attach a listener to `sv-report`'s scope, and swap out properties of that scope. I understand that it's possible to grab the sibling scopes, but that causes problems when trying to figure out exactly which element it's attached to.

I attempted the following:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    ele = element;
    var actualScopyThingy = element.scope();
},
```

Which I had *assumed* would give me the scope of the element the attribute was defined on, but alas, it still returns the *parent* scope of the element.

If it's important, `sv-report` is defined as the following, but I'd like to be able to keep it the same (since `sv-reloadable` is going to be attached to many different elements, all of which *must* have `viewModel` defined on their scope)

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'sv-report/sv-report.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      id: '=',
      reportParameters: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, svAnalytics) {
      /* unrelated code here */
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      initialLoadReport(scope);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, `isolateScope()` is what I was after (rather than `scope()`). `sv-reloadable`'s directive becomes:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var elementScope = element.isolateScope();
            elementScope.$on('parameter-changed', function(evt, payload) {
                ...
            });
        }
    };
```